# Cannot click on an element

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor

I have an element that I have tried every known way to click on here are a few:

```
var areaMap = $('[data-bind="click: campusMap"]');
var areaMap = browser.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.campus-map.panel > div.panel-footer > button.btn.btn-browse")).click();
var areaMap = element(by.cssContainingText('button.btn', "View Area Map"));

//and this way too

browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', areaMap.getWebElement()); 
browser.actions().mouseMove(areaMap).click().perform();
```

I have no idea how to make this element interact-able.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="campus-map panel" data-bind="click: campusMap">
  <div class="title">Area Map</div>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div id="googleContainer" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; cursor: pointer;">
          <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="gmnoprint" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 166px; bottom: 0px; width: 121px;">
              <div style="background-color: white; padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 118px; position: absolute; left: 36px; top: 5px;">
                <div class="gmnoscreen" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                  <div class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; -moz-user-select: none; right: 95px; bottom: 0px;" draggable="false">
                    <div class="svg-controls" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; bottom: 13px; right: 0px;">
                      <div class="gm-style-cc" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: @Sam thank you for cleaning that up :)

Comment: did you try ng-click?

Comment: @ruby I cannot alter the html and I do not believe this is an angular page.  I have buttons all over the page, this one just for whatever reason does not want to be clicked on

Comment: if it's not an angular page why is this tagged angular? Check if element even exists when you run your code. That selector looks weird

Comment: @charlietfl because protractor and angular-js go hand in hand.  I can use angularjs element finders by ignoring sync

Comment: are you making sure the div is loaded before you try and acces it ?

Comment: if the map is loaded when the page is loaded try wrapping your code in a window.onload  block

Comment: @Tim I had an expected condition that waited for element to visible in the dom, which it is, just will not click.

Comment: if you using a third party lib, it might be capturing the event and stoping you from using it

Comment: try and attach an event handler to the parent div and do a conditional check using event delegation

Comment: does the map live inside of panel-footer?

Comment: @Tim I cannot alter anything besides my protractor tests or I would change things around a bit.  I checked using the selenium IDE and it is finding the element.

Comment: Gathering context from these comments, I'm assuming that you are testing a system that you did not write and are not allowed to modify.  Some questions to consider:  Are we sure that clicking that particular button is supposed to do something?  Do we have access to the javascript source (assuming JS based on tags), or just the HTML?  Is it possible that a parent element has an event handler, or that the button is set up with something other than an onClick listener?

Comment: @Grumble the element button does not have an onClick event itself, however the container does.  It is injecting a google map picture and a button underneath that allows for viewing.  I can click on this button on the webpage itself. I have access to the .html and likely the .js using the dev tools however I have not tested yet using .js only what is on the html. I have tried clicking on everything that the panel allows.  I will update the html.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps grabbing the button's container and clicking it instead of the button will solve the problem, then?

Comment: I suspect that you'll need to visit the js to figure out how the page works.  You'll be able to see which elements have event handlers and which do not.

Comment: @Grumble yes I'll have to do some more investigating I just tried grabbing the container but had no luck.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. You didn't specify which element you are trying to click. If I were to guess, it would be the first `DIV`. Your other code attempts are referencing a `BUTTON` that isn't in the HTML. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code has elements that do not exist in your html example... so I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to click on. But assuming it's the first div, and assuming it's *visible*, this selector should work:

`var areaMap = $('div.campus-map.panel');`

or if that's NOT visible, perhaps this (since title should be visible):

`var areaMap = $('div.campus-map.panel div.title');`

Or with text:

`var areaMap = element(by.cssContainingText('div.title', "Area Map"));`